# Using puppeteer to get a list of elements and text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to fetch a list of elements and get the src value of the `img` and the `span` of each item, and also the two `data` attributes.

Here's one item example:

```
<div class="slick-list">
<div class="item clearfix ng-scope" ng-repeat="related in relatedColors" slick-carousel-item="" style="width: 25%; display: inline-block;">
            <a ng-class="mainColor.color.colorName == related.color.colorName ? 'current-color' : ''" data-color-id="152484" data-style-id="9053" id="related-color" tabindex="0">
                <img ng-src="https://somesite.com/image.jpg">
                <span ng-bind="related.color.colorName" class="ng-binding">Dynasty</span>
            </a>
        </div>
...
    </div>
```

The list of items is `wrapped` in a div class called `slick-list`.

Here's my attempt at getting this:

```
const variations = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slick-list .item")).map((el) => {
    console.log(el);
    return el.querySelector("span").textContent;
  })
);
```

This returns what looks like a jQuery object, and I'm not sure how to parse it.

```
{ jQuery224079785371304925891: [Object] },
```

Here's my code:

```
  const hrefs = await page.$$eval("a.product-image", (elements) =>
    elements.map((el) => {
      console.log(el);
      return el.href;
    })
  );
  const urls = hrefs.map((el) => el);
  for (const url of urls) {
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const t = document.querySelector(".main-info h2").textContent;
      console.log(t);
    });
    const product_name = await page.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector(".main-info h2").textContent
    );
    const category = await page.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector(".main-info h3").textContent
    );
const variations = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slick-list .item")).map((el) => {
    return el.querySelector("span")
  })
);
    const product_obj = {
      product_name,
      category,
      variations,
    };
    console.log(product_obj); // { product_name: 'Pleasant Touch', category: 'SmartStrand Silk', variations: {} }
  }
```

How can I get the data needed so I can include it in `product_obj`?

Comment: That looks right, just use `map` instead of `forEach` (and return instead of console.log)

Comment: @pguardiario I don't get any results from updating to this, updated code. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue was that I was missing a `.` (dot) for .item selector. It seems like it's working but I'm unsure how to parse the jQuery object here.

Comment: None of the `evaluate` funcs look like they're returning any jQuery objects. Please share the actual site and a [mcve] (although I'm aware it's an old post, it's a search result hit I'd like to answer if I can).